# Include c++ header in all cpp files from cmake

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake

Is there any way to include a header (.hpp) in all cpp files from a project (automatic)?

The project is compiled using cmake.

Comment: And you used the C language tag because of ... .?

Comment: Forcefully including something in TU is naughty. Why do you even want to do that? I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Big project with lots of files (c++ and c) and I would like to add some common functions in all of them

Comment: Sounds like you want to "force include" files, but as far as I know there is not direct support for this in CMake. So do you need this to be cross-platform or would it be enough to have it for GNU or VS compilers?

Comment: you are planning to also add calls to that functions in an automated manner? really quite unclear why you would need that.

Comment: @tobi303 overwrite new/delete

Comment: @CrSe - Is that it? You just need to link a TU that replaces them once. No need to force include anything.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @StoryTeller more info on this?

Comment: [\[new.delete\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/new.delete), from the C++ standard itself. Notice how it says *"A C++ program may define functions with either of these function signatures, and thereby displace the default versions defined by the C++ standard library."* The replacement is global across the entire program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre-compiled headers to that. Cross-compile implementation of that for CMake is not very easy, so, I recommend 3rd party module for that, for example [CMakePCHCompiler](https://github.com/nanoant/CMakePCHCompiler)